# How to setup RCurl headers in R for Tinder API

Tags: r, rcurl

This is probably a stupid question, but for some reason I can't get my head around the RCurl headers in R in order to access an API. I'm trying to authenticate with the Tinder API, and have already authenticated to Facebook (using Rfacebook), but when authenticating to Tinder, all I get is `Error: Forbidden`. Here's what I have so far (the last two lines is where I think the problem is):

```
library(Rfacebook)
library(devtools)
library(RCurl)

appID<-'MYAPPID'
appSecret<-'MYAPPSECRET'

fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id=appID, app_secret=appSecret)
me <- getUsers("me",token=fb_oauth)
fbID <- me$id

save(fb_oauth,file="fb_oauth")
load("fb_oauth")

my_Token <- toString(fb_oauth$credentials)
my_httpheader <- c("Content-type='application/json', User-agent='User-Agent: Tinder/3.0.4'")

myTest <- postForm("https://api.gotinder.com/auth", facebook_id=fbID, facebook_token=my_Token, .opts=list(httpheader=my_httpheader))
```

I'm assuming my problem is the headers, and [here's what Tinder's API says about the headers](https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467). But it just returns `Error: Forbidden` which isn't really helpful for troubleshooting.

Any suggestions about what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try using `httr` instead of RCurl. As the `Rfacebook`-Package relies on it as well i guess that the token is ready to use by further `httr` functions

Comment: Are you able to submit a curl request from the command line and get that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out the new and still improving curlconverter package.  You give it the curl request and it creates an httr script for you. I took these from the github link you have.

```
library(curlconverter)

fbPost <- "curl -X POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth --data '{\"facebook_token\": fb_token, \"facebook_id\": fb_user_id}'"

tinderPost <- "curl -X POST https://api.tinder.com/profile --data '{\"age_filter_min\": 26, \"gender\": 1, \"age_filter_max\": 32, \"distance_filter\": 14}'"

fb <- make_req(straighten(fbPost))
fb
# [[1]]
# function () 
# httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "https://api.gotinder.com/auth", 
#     body = list(`{` = ""))

tinder <- make_req(straighten(tinderPost))
tinder

# [[1]]
# function () 
# httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "https://api.tinder.com/profile", 
#     body = list(`{` = ""))
```

Then you can copy and paste that result. So,

```
fbResp <- httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "https://api.gotinder.com/auth", 
    body = list(`{` = ""))

tinderResp <- httr::VERB(verb = "POST", url = "https://api.tinder.com/profile", 
    body = list(`{` = ""))
```

To get you json response work a little jsonlite magic

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(content(tinderResp, as = 'text'))
jsonlite::fromJSON(content(fbResp, as = 'text'))
```

Comment: This looks really promising! so it looks like I need to call fb[[1]]() and tinder[[1]](), and I can save it with a response that tells me how many bytes of data were in the response, but how do you call it to actually see the json data that comes out?